Class 'Home' has no instance method 'call'
I attempted to use the Home widget in my Flutter app to handle a callback function named addToCart, which was intended to add a product to the cart.
I expected that, when invoking the addToCart method within the Home widget, it would correctly trigger the addToCart function passed down to child widgets, such as ProductTileWidget, allowing me to interact with the cart functionality.
Instead, it gives an error:
Class 'Home' has no instance method 'call'.
Receiver: Instance of 'Home'
Tried calling:
call(addToCart: Closure: (ProductDataModel) => void from Function 'addToCart':., cartItems: Instance(length:0) of '_GrowableList')


Show your code.  You're trying to invoke an instance of a Home widget as a function somewhere.

Yes, we really need to see more of that Home class, so that we know what type of class it is and what comes before that call statement.
